# symfony : Problem 'Integrity constraint violation' with primary key

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine, primary-key

When I want to create a new object with one of my form, Doctrine take me an error :

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Creating worked previously, but I don't know what I have change to have an error now.

My schema for ID :

```
Logement:
  connection: doctrine
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  tableName: logement
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(2)
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
```

In my forms : BaseLogementForm.class.php

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
             'id' => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
              ... other widgets);

$this->setValidators(array(
             'id' => new sfValidatorCHoice(array('choices' => array($this->getObject()->get('id')), 'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->get('id'), 'required' => false)),
             ... other validators);
```

**Edit :**

I give you, my functions

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request){
  // Retourne un formulaire pour la création d'un nouveau logement
    $this->form = new logementForm();
  }

  public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request){
  // Génére un formulaire pour la création d'un nouveau logement

    $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST));

    $this->form = new logementForm();

    $this->processForm($request, $this->form);

    // Affichage du formulaire dans le template "newSuccess"
    $this->setTemplate('new');
  }

  protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form){
  // Vérifie les données d'un formulaire et les enregistre dans la base

    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));

    // On teste pour savoir dans quel cas on se situe : création/modification
    // Si il s'agit d'une création :
    if ($form->getObject()->isNew()) {
        // Vérification de la validité des données entrées
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Si les données sont valides, enregistrement dans la base
            $logement = $form->save(); 

            // On vérifie que l'enregistrement à bien eu lieu
            if ($form->save()) {
                $this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', 'Création du logement effectuée');
            }
            else {
                $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'Erreur lors de la création du logement');
            }

            // Redirection vers la fiche du logement nouvellement créé
            $this->redirect('logement/fiche?id='.$logement->getId());   
        }
        // Sinon affichage d'un message d'erreur
        else {
            $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'Informations saisies non valides');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... well there's nothing wrong with your base form or your schema definition. It looks like you're unsetting the id of an existing record and trying to save it or something... How are you creating/modifying the form object before saving?

Comment: I add methods to save object. I have found where is the error, but I don't understand how I can delete it.

The problem is my tests to know if I create an object or if I update.

How can I know this ?

because the error come from $form->getObject->isNew().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your type is integer(2), that's mean you only can have 100 elements in your table. I guess that in element 101, the db engine try to write 0 as id.